# How to Install Mysql in Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.7?

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, redhat

I need to install Mysql in Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.7 how do i do it.I HAVE NEVER WORKED IN A LINUX ENVIRONMENT SO ANY BASIC HELP WILL ALSO BE HELPFUL.

Comment: basic help - please read manuals and use google

Answer (score 2):

```
yum install mysql-server mysql
```

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-mysql-under-rhel/